# Unexpected shutdown when not charging

Tags: laptop, battery-life

I have come across an issue with my laptop today,it is a toshiba satellite and it is more than 3 years old.

I unplugged it earlier today and after a couple of minutes,it shut down instantly;no blue screens,no error messages,much like a pc shuts down when unplugged.

After that,i plugged it back in and carried on with my stuff.However,i tried to uplug it again and the exact same thing happened;twice actually.

What do you think?Should i get it cleaned?Should i buy a new battery?

Cheers

Comment: Buy a new battery the old one not charging anymore

Answer (score 0):

Batteries get old, and especially when you never use the battery (being plugged in all the time), it dies an early death. That shows by its capacity being reduced to 1 or 2%, or - finally - 0%.

Your description matches exactly that behavior, so I think your battery is just gone. If you have the chance to try your battery on a identical model, you can confirm that, but it is a 99% sure assumption. So I recommend you buy a new battery (or live with keeping it plugged in all the time).

You can alleviate that issue (with the new battery) by unplugging the power cable once a week, letting it go down to 5%, and then plugging back in (although it is quite obnoxious if you forget it and walk away with everything open and it dies on you). That should give your battery a longer live, and even after 3-4 years, it should have 40-60 % capacity. On the other hand, how long will you have that computer?